# How to perform machine learning on multi-variate timeseries in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series

I’ve got a clinical dataset containing multi-variate timeseries (mts) data (e.g. heart frequency, blood pressure etc.) of 500 different patients. I would like to apply machine learning on these datasets. My aim is to classify each time series by predicting whether the patient survived or deceased. Another classification task would be to predict a specific disease (e.g. sepsis, myocardial infarction etc.).
Which algorithms can handle multiple multivariate time series and which R packages can deal with this? I’ve only come along with the “mlmts”-Package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlmts/mlmts.pdf)  which only offers the kNN-Algorithm for MTS and a feature-based algorithm.
Are there ML algorithms that can handle lists of data and a vector containing labels like below?

```
> data
[[1]]
x y z 
3 4 5
3 6 8
7 2 2    

[[2]]
x y z 
1 1 8
1 1 5
9 5 3 

[[3]]
x y z 
5 1 3
1 9 3
9 3 6

> labels
labels               
     1      0      1
```